# Movie with a man/woman fighting over a giant truck in the desert

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I saw this movie a while ago and I remember a lot of images of huge desert landscapes and a man/woman fighting over the control of a huge truck (or maybe they had a truck each and were fighting over something else, I can't remember straight).

The truck was an armored vehicle roughly the size of a semi-truck without the trailer. The movie should have been relatively recent but seemed to be quite low-budget.

I believe it should have been a post-apocalyptic movie but I can't really remember anything about the story, just those images.

**The footage of the movie had colour editing and it was saturated in tones of orange, it should be easy to identify by this colour treatment since it's something you don't see very often.**

Comment: It wasn't Mad Max 2: The Road Warrior, by any chance? Trucks, fighting, lots of wide shots of Australia's red deserts...

Comment: Hello, no it was something far more alternative and experimental. The film was really slow paced apart from a couple of action scenes and the trucks were much bigger. Also the movie seemed rather recent, maybe 2000 onwards.

Comment: My friend told me it was terminal virus. http://www.post-apocalypse.co.uk/tv.html I don't know, it doesn't sound kosher.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock: No trucks mentioned in the review, at the least, but the coloration and the post-apoc setup might work...

Comment: Roughly speaking, how long ago was "a while ago"? Was it in English? Did it seem to be a tv movie, or a cinematic movie?

Comment: The description is a big vague, but it reminds me of DoomsDay
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_(film))

Comment: It seemed like a TV movie, english, low budget and it has to be from 2000-2010. It's not Doomsday either, I've seen that one.

Comment: @S3nd41:
Does *Terminal Virus* mentioned above ring any bells?

Comment: Was my answer the right one?

Comment: Sorry but it's not this one. This one was kind of a recent low-budget art-house-wannabe movie.

Comment: It seemed like a quite recent TV movie, the image quality was good.

Comment: Can't believe nobody had proposed Mad Max : Fury Road at this point. It fits the requirements (2000 onwards and man/woman fighting over a giant truck, the color editing). All depends of how long is "a while ago".

Comment: So, did you ever find the title of this film?

Comment: Can you comment on the existing answers, as to how they don't match? It will help elicit details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be the 1983 film *[Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/)*?

As can be seen in this clip from YouTube, it has some very saturated oranges.

If so, yours is a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113440/19561).

Comment: I think it could have been this one, the footage at 3:25 does seem familiar as well as the girl but I could have sworn the truck was much bigger and heavily armored with a very simple geometric exterior.

Answer (score 4):

As @iliveunderawesomerock mentioned, this could be "[Terminal Virus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113607/)", a low-budget made-for-TV movie from 1995.

As you can see from the screenshots, the film was set in a post-apocalyptic desert. There was extensive use of an orange filter (presumably to disguise the poor quality of the film-stock used) and a scene where one of the film's many large-breasted amazonian women strangles a man who's been hiding behind a vehicle.

[image]

[image]

You can view the film (alas, with Russian dubbing) online [here](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/8093992/terminal_virus_1995/)

Answer (score 4):

I have been looking for a similar film and have found [*Terminus* (1987)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(1987_film))

> In the year 2037, an international sport has been established, wherein a driver of a truck must cross the country and arrive at a designated terminus, while confronting obstacles and enemies along the way. The lead truck, named "Monster", has been designed by a boy genius (Gabriel Damon) and is to be piloted through the course by a woman named Gus (Karen Allen). Eventually, the truck's AI fails and Gus ends up in uncharted territories. There, she encounters leather-clad "hoods" (hoodlums) that torture her and eventually kill her. Prior to dying, she befriends a fellow prisoner (Johnny Hallyday), who later uses the truck to rescue himself and a young orphan. Meanwhile, the boy genius watches them by an artificial satellite so that he may see how well the truck's software works. The conclusion reveals that as he watches the truck, he is himself watched and evaluated by the sinister doctor (Jürgen Prochnow) who cloned him.

### Trailer

Answer (score 4):

The 1977 film *[Damnation Alley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damnation_Alley_(film))* has some scenes with over-saturated oranges as well, as can be seen on YouTube.

It is based on a book by Roger Zelazny of the same title.

Answer (score 2):

The 1984 film *Starship*, also released as *Lorca and the Outlaws*, and *2084*, does involve a fight over a giant truck in a desert landscape, although I feel like you would have mentioned the android.

> On the remote mining planet Ordessa, the management uses killer military police androids to crack down on workers upset with the terrible conditions. Lorca (John Tarrant) and his mother Abbie (Donogh Rees) led the human underground resistance movement until Abbie was killed by androids. Now, Lorca and Suzi (Cassandra Webb) battle Captain Jowitt (Ralph Cotterill) and the brutal bounty hunter Danny (Hugh Keays-Byrne), with the help of the friendly android Grid (Deep Roy).

[This review](http://mjsimpson-films.blogspot.com/2014/02/lorca-and-outlaws.html) specifically mentions the fight.

> Somehow - don’t ask me how - Lorca and Grid end up at a big open-cast mine with giant lorries, the sort that have tyres 20 feet in diameter. This futuristic setting with its futuristic vehicles is represented by a big open-cast mine with giant lorries, the sort that have tyres 20 feet in diameter. There is no attempt whatsoever to disguise this cool but badly-used location.

....

> On returning, he is captured by Danny (Hugh Keays-Byrne: Mad Max, Les Patterson Saves the World, Farscape: The Peacekeeper Wars and the 1999 version of Journey to the Centre of the Earth), a grimacing, unkempt bounty hunter employed by Captain Jowitt (tick another cliché box, folks; heck, tick a bunch of them) who has already captured Grid and uses him as bait. The two rebels are thrown into the back of a giant truck with a single droid guard who is easily overcome. There follows a deeply unthrilling ‘fight’ between Lorca and Danny which ends with the truck rolling gently into a wall of earth with a small explosion to suggest that it has crashed in some way (they couldn’t actually damage the thing of course, on account of how much those trucks cost). Danny is thrown into the earthbank but we later see his hand emerge so he’s - gasp - not dead. Lorca repairs Grid, whose head has come off.

You can see some clips of the movie in this bit featuring the music of Genesis, who scored the film: