# Post apocalypse movie from the 70s or 80s with a truck in it

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

For years I have been trying to track down a film that I saw a clip of on an old BBC show called *Screen Test*.

They introduced the film as "having used the most scrap from scrap yards than any other film."

It was either an Australian or a New Zealand film. Post apocalyptic like *Mad Max*. In-fact for years I thought *Mad Max* would be the film, but it wasn't.

They showed one scene from the film which the contestants answered questions on.

> A six wheel truck drives up to the camera. It looks like a *Mad Max* truck. There are at least two people in the truck, a man sits close to us with a woman next to him. He looks through binoculars (sci-fi bins). He sees a long trailer thing on rails and it has sails. Then this land ship is attacked by bandits on motorbikes or something. The sails fall and people run about panicking. Then we cut back to the truck and it drives away.

The film is not *Battletruck* or *Damnation Alley*. The truck I think had six wheels, but I could be wrong. Not evenly spaced wheels, with the second wheels set back. A gun slung at the back, like a chain gun. It was futuristic like and pointy like a Lambo, not a square truck. In black or dark grey.

Like this but with another set of wheels at the back and painted dark:

[image: iamge of a wildcat]

It probably wasn't a very good film and has dropped below the radar of obscurity. Anyone who could help ID this film for me would be greatly appreciated.

You can see how obsessed I am as still making models of it in Lego:

[image: image of a 6-wheeled Lego truck]

Here is a bad drawing of what I remember:

[image]

Comment: This user was asking about the same film on [Yahoo answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081014140550AAtKVGD)

Comment: [This may help you](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-10-stupidest-and-most-shameless-mad-max-rip-offs-5700413)

Comment: This was me askign about it years back, and that was when I found it wasn't Damnation Alley

Comment: Mix of sci-fi and Mad-Max; Could it be [Metalstorm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085935/)?

Comment: The truck is going in the right direction style-wise but it seems rather flimsy, I remember the one in the clip being a bit more solid, but it was a long time ago now.

Comment: Oh, I found _Damnation Alley_, but then I saw you had that one covered. Its Wikipedia page however, mentions a TV series, _[Ark II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_II)_. How about that?

Comment: I wonder, as far as i could read, Screen test is a child show, so i would wonder if the showed parts of a violent movie, like mad max or other rated post apocaliptic movies. So could this be the Child TV-Series The ARKII which has an vehicle like you described:https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/8f/20/028f2065543cabb7b89719d0d87c9fec.jpg Had this as answer first, but moved it to a comment, because it is an american series, are you sure it was australian or new zealand?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they said it was filmed in New Zealand or Australia, however that doesn't mean it wasn't made by a USA company I suppose. I found ArkII today, and yes, the concept is close. Though somehow the actual Ark truck seems a lot more flashy and bigger than the clip I remember, and yes, the film would have to have been child friendly I expect, as yes, it was shown on a children's show.

Comment: I've just added a bad drawing of what I remember.

Comment: Thinking of [Megaforce](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084316/) but upon looking at the pic of the truck (http://www.chud.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/VEHICLE-PROMO-PHOTO-RETOUCH.jpg) perhaps not.

Comment: Oh wow, so close, but I feel it was altogether less glam sci-fi and more black leathers and black vehicles, post apocalyptic style. However seeing that truck makes me start to doubt my memory!

Comment: just found Warriors Of The Wasteland 1983 on youtube, though awful the concept is heading in the right direction

Comment: your lego model is awesome, can you add more pictures?

Comment: More pics of the lego version:
http://justintuijl.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/lego-battletruck.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/)

[image: Scrambler]

Comment: Are you suggesting the Scrambler or another vehicle in the movie?

Comment: Yea, that is totally it. Looks like I made the truck better in my head as a kid. Thanks so much for this answer!!

Comment: @JustinTuijl: Is The Scrambler, the picture I added, the one you're thinking of?

Comment: Yes it was The Scrambler I was referencing, the scene from the movie, it is all the one I was looking for. the land ship with sails, it is all there as I remember, but for the fact that I made the truck a lot better in my head than it really is! And added a set of wheels!!

Comment: Wow. The SFX look pretty good for an 80's B movie, or did the review just pick the good scenes?

Comment: I think they put all the effort into the effects and not much else, from what they said.

I just worked out it took 32 years to find the answer to this question!

Comment: Here is a good review of the film: https://mossfilm.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/spacehunter-adventures-in-the-forbidden-zone-film-review/

Answer (score 1):

I know you said it's not [Battletruck](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084887/) but I'm reasonably sure you're talking about Battletruck. It was made in New Zealand and is frequently spoken of as a Mad Max clone.

Comment: I watched for over a minute before I realized this is not the trailer, it's the whole dang movie

Comment: No, I'm sorry but it isn't Battletruck. The truck isn't the right truck. I watched this years ago thinking I had found the film, but no, it just isn't the one. thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Damnation Alley? 
First Lieutenant Jake Tanner (Jan-Michael Vincent) shares ICBM silo duty at an American air force missile base in the Californian desert with Major Eugene "Sam" Denton (George Peppard), who is requesting not to work with him. On their way to duty, Denton talks to Airman Tom Keegan (Paul Winfield), an aspiring artist. When the United States detects incoming nuclear missiles from the Soviet Union, Tanner and Denton launch part of the retaliatory strike. The United States is hit hard, although it manages to intercept 40% of Soviet missiles.

Two years later, the Earth has been tilted off its axis by nuclear detonations of World War III; radiation has mutated insect life, the planet is wracked by massive storms, and the sky is in a perpetual aurora borealis-like state. Tanner has resigned his commission and has been scouting Barstow while Keegan, who has also left the Air Force, has been painting as an artist in one of the base's out-buildings. Mutated giant scorpions menace the area. Later an airman falls asleep in a bunk and drops a lit cigarette onto a pile of Playboy magazines, which causes the entire base to catch fire and explode, killing most of its inhabitants including the base commander, General Lander (Murray Hamilton). Keegan and Tanner are unscathed, as are Denton and Lieutenant Tom Perry (Kip Niven), who were in an underground garage bunker.[image]

Comment: He says in his question that it is not, and he has confirmed Spacehunter. Still, your answer could be useful to later querents.

Answer (score 0):

Ark II TV Series (1976)

"Three young scientists travel around the country in the 25th century after the world has been ravaged by pollution. In their hi-tech RV (called Ark II), they study the land and help out those in need." (IMDB)

[IMDB][1]

[You Tube][1]: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0127989/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

Comment: Afraid that wasn't the one, too slick, turns out it was Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone